# Eclipse getting too slow - workspace recreation helped

Tags: eclipse, performance, workspace

My Eclipse was getting slower and slower over time. Tips I found on the Internet did not help.
What I did is completely deleted my workspace, created new one and reimported all my projects into the new workspace and this really made the difference.

So my question is whether it's possible to perform this workspace clean-up without deleting and recreating workspace...
Maybe there is some cache in workspace which is getting big? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Slow in which ways? Im finding GWT validation is slowing and starting a new workspace helps for example..

Comment: Hi i have provided the solution.
Can you please try that.
Thanks

Answer (score 30):

Eclipse keeps track of all changes in local history. That might introduce slowdown over time.
Local history is located at `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history`.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Can I completely remove that .history folder without any risk?

Comment: Yes, but I recently found out that you can reduce the number of days to keep in history, such that the history doesn't grow too big. (Preferences->General->Workspace->Local history)

Answer (score 14):

Not sure about newer versions of eclipse, but in 3.1 settings in

> Preferences->General->Workspace->Local history

did not work for me. I had it set by default to 7 days but files were kept for 4 years. And I guess other people here had the same issue.

For me it helped to remove history files manually from

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history.
```

Answer (score 4):

I use RAD 7.5 (which is based off of Eclipse 3.4). I found several of my projects had *millions* of history files, all older than 7 days, and mostly the same dummy MANIFEST.MF file (39 bytes).

I discovered this when I tried to delete an old project with Windows Explorer. After 12 hours, Windows Explorer reported that it had recycled 3.5 million files, and was still working.

I found the only way to remove the workspace was to open a Command Window, CD to

```
<project>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.history
```

then type

```
DEL *.* /s/q
```

Even this took the better part of an hour.

Answer (score 2):

Try running eclipse from command prompt with

```
eclipse.exe -clean
```

More http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-10280.html

Comment: I actually did run it with -clean prior to deleting the workspace... -clean didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes due to Physical Memory issue it cant build the workspace.
So To remove Memory issues update @

> eclipse.ini

file as below

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solve the problem by deleting all stuffs inside eclipse's directory OPTReplica. after that, re-stat eclipse, for me it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is programmed as a filebomb, and it causes a large variety of problem, evben on modern robust filesystem. Problem can goes from large waste of diskspace for nothing to preventing your OS to boot if your workspace is on your OS partition. Eclipse is programmed as a filebomb.

The cleanup mechanism in eclipse doesn't work, so the only viable option is to frequently cleanup your workspace by hand at regular interval, or to add your cleanup code to a sh file that does it before launching eclipse.

An other option will be to introduce the eclipse developpers to the fabulous world of databases that produce faster to run and easier to write code. Sadly a rhumor says that they will shot on sight everyone that pronounce the words "sqlite" or "jdbc", and will sacrifice virgind every sunday to the all-mighty-god-of-filebombs.