# GWT/GPE Development / Eclipse Slow - Workspace recreation helped

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins, workspace

Im finding after a few weeks of GWT development my Development Mode compilations suddenly slow down at the stage where you see this in the Development Mode console log:

```
Validating newly compiled units
```

I've found a related question but this seemed a little vague compared to my issue

[Eclipse getting too slow - workspace recreation helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386119/eclipse-getting-too-slow-workspace-recreation-helped)

Since I lose window/toolbar layout settings (even if export/import prefs) and other useful things when I recreate the workspace I want to find out which files I can clean?

I've [raised a bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7036&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars) with GWT..

Comment: Ive checked all my workspace files into Git locally, Im going to checkpoint regularly and see what happens to cause the corruption

Comment: I found 35Gb of generated GWT temp files which Ive cleared out, I'll be interested to see if that makes any difference..

Comment: It doesnt, the issue is definitely localised to the eclipse workspace and recreating that (with all same settings) clears issue

Comment: This solved the issue for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19909401/1040124

Answer (score 2):

Another answer which really solved it in my case.

Is it possible that you are operating behind a proxy which has to be configured in Preferences->General->Network Connections (e.g. for installing plugins)?

That's true in my case but I had deactivated the proxy settings to reach the in-house SVN. As it seemed, the Validation routine always tries to download ui binder XSDs without success which takes a lot of time.

Concerning my comment in my first answer: yes, it run a lot faster after reinstallation but the reason was that I had to activate the proxy settings for reinstallation. Once I deactivated it again for an SVN commit, it ran slow again ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I actually tackled the validation performance issue seperately unfortunately this issue affects the compilation and run steps. There is something created in the eclipse workspace that causes it because if I re-create it, everything is fine again (no proxy settings changes)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems with Eclipse (Indigo Service Release 1 Build id: 20110916-0149)
and the GWT plugin. Especially when starting Eclipse, Validating the GWT components in my project takes ages.

Googling revealed that the GWT designer in combination with a 64Bit Eclipse Indigo causes this issue.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6602

I wil try to reinstall the GWT plugin without Designer.

Comment: thanks for sharing, I have an overly(!) powerful machine and start eclipse in seconds, it's specifically the verification step that goes bad for me

Comment: Yes, same for me. And de- and reinstallation of the GWT plugin improved it a lot

Comment: Thanks for sharing, hopefully this may help others